# Hide Resource Management Context Menu entries from a view

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, contextmenu

I have a custom view in my eclipse RCP and want to hide some of the actions from org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources.ResourceMgmtActions when a user right clicks on a IProject resource. I just want to display "refresh" action and hide Close, Open, Close Unrelated projects, Build option from the context menu. Is there a way to do this declaratively via plugin.xml or  pro grammatically without copying the code from ResourceMgmtActionProvider.java?

Comment: You may be able to do it with the `org.eclipse.ui.activities` extension point.

Comment: Thanks for the reply greg-449. If I use activity pattern binding, will it not disable the context menu for all the views and not just the view that I do not want the menus to appear?

Comment: That depends on how these menu items are defined and what patterns you use. I can't tell you that without a lot of research.